# How to silence botframework logging in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, logging, botframework

I would like to know how to control the botframework logger used by `ChatConnector.js` to silence output to stdout.

I could output my logs to a separate file but this isn't my goal here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so after some further digging into the internal `logger.js` file it looks like this is only a problem when using the botframework emulator app.

In production those logs won't appear unless the `NODE_DEBUG` environment variable is set.